# Serialize a enum with Collection properties to JSON string

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, deserialization

Below ReceivePartyPlaylistEvent  object i am trying to serialize using GSON library. This has association on Playlist and Song class.

```
public final class ReceivePartyPlaylistEvent extends Event {
        private PartyPlayList partyPlayList;

}
```

and **PartyPlaylist** is an **enum** as i needed it to be **single instance**

```
    public enum PartyPlayList implements Playlist{
    INSTANCE;

    private List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Song> getSongList() {
        return songList;
    }
}
```

and  the song object be like. two classes extend this Song object and implement the abstract methods.

```
    public abstract class Song{
    private String songID;
    private String trackTitle;
    private String trackAlbum;
    private String trackArtist;
    private String albumArtUrl;
    .... setters and getters...

    }
```

Now when i try to serialize **ReceivePartyPlaylistEvent** using **GSON(2.2.4)** it is giving me a blank output.
so how can i serialize this.

Serialize:

```
//_receivePartyPlaylistEvent has dummy values in it.
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(_receivePartyPlaylistEvent );
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned anything to `partyPlayList` so it's null by default and Gson will not serialize it.

Try:

```
private PartyPlayList partyPlayList = PartyPlayList.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: No thats not the case, In the test case i have added dummy playlist with a collection of songs